# for each loop incremement

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, post-increment

I just try to understand why these two loops are not doing the same.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        array[j]++;
    }
for(int i: array){
        i++;
}
```

or in other words, why does the second not increment?

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Are you using Java ?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you don't assign the value. The value just gets lost. The braces in the first case take care of the assignment. In the second version you just take the value and don't assign it. However it also gets incremented in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Because in array[j] you are modifying value in array under array reference. int i is not reference to value in array. int is primitive data type. It is only int value that was copied to your local variable i.

Answer (score 0):

`array[j]++` means increment the value stored at `array[j]` by one, So the first loop increments all the values in the array by one. The second loop is a for-each loop, which is equivalent to:

```
for(Iterator<Integer> iterator = iterator.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer i = iterator.next();
    i++;
}
```

As you can see we never change to value referenced by the array, only the local variable referenced by the for-each loop.